# Swift string manipulation causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, string, crash, swift, exc-bad-access

I'm working on a time calculator to try to learn Swift, and I'm running into an issue where formatting the user's input is causing bad access errors.

Here is the code that's causing the crash (originally contained in a loop but broken up to try to find the problem):

```
var outputString : String = ""
let prefixString : String = "00"

let combinedString1 : String = prefixString + self.timeIntervalInput[0]
let combinedString1a : String = combinedString1.substringFromIndex(countElements(combinedString1) - 2)
outputString += combinedString1a

let combinedString2 : String = prefixString + self.timeIntervalInput[1]
let combinedString2a : String = combinedString2.substringFromIndex(countElements(combinedString2) - 2)
outputString += combinedString2a    // CRASH USUALLY HAPPENS HERE

let combinedString3 : String = prefixString + self.timeIntervalInput[2]
let combinedString3a : String = combinedString3.substringFromIndex(countElements(combinedString3) - 2)
outputString += combinedString3a
```

The user's input is stored in an array of strings (hours/minutes/seconds/milliseconds).  The above code is supposed to fill in the gaps with 0s (so 2 becomes 02, an empty string becomes 00, etc), and is run each time the user's input is updated.

The above code crashes after the first or second character is entered.  Changing the prefixString from let to var causes it to work correctly for slightly longer, so that it crashes after the third character instead.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a bug in Swift?

**Edit (additional info):**

Here's the entire struct:

```
struct TimeCalcInput
{
    var timeIntervalInput : String[] = ["", "", "", ""]
    var timeIntervalIndex : Int = 0
    var decimalInput : String = ""
    var timeType : TimeTypeEnum = TimeTypeEnum.AM
    var potentialInput : String = ""

    var label : String {
        get {

            if (self.timeType == TimeTypeEnum.Decimal) {
                return self.decimalInput
            } else {
//              var outputString : String = ""
//              for (var i : Int = 0; i < 3; i++) {
//                  let prefixString : String = "00"
//                  var combinedString : String = ""
//                  combinedString += prefixString + self.timeIntervalInput[i]
//                  combinedString = combinedString.substringFromIndex(countElements(combinedString) - 2)
//                  outputString = outputString + "\(combinedString)"
//              }
                var outputString : String = ""
                let prefixString : String = "00"

                let combinedString1 : String = prefixString + self.timeIntervalInput[0]
                let combinedString1a : String = combinedString1.substringFromIndex(countElements(combinedString1) - 2)
                outputString += combinedString1a

                let combinedString2 : String = prefixString + self.timeIntervalInput[1]
                let combinedString2a : String = combinedString2.substringFromIndex(countElements(combinedString2) - 2)
                outputString += combinedString2a    // CRASH USUALLY HAPPENS HERE

                let combinedString3 : String = prefixString + self.timeIntervalInput[2]
                let combinedString3a : String = combinedString3.substringFromIndex(countElements(combinedString3) - 2)
                outputString += combinedString3a

                return ""
                let test : String = "000"
                var asd : String = test + self.timeIntervalInput[3]
                asd = asd.substringFromIndex(countElements(asd) - 3)
                outputString += asd

                if (self.timeType == TimeTypeEnum.AM) {
                    outputString += " AM"
                } else if (self.timeType == TimeTypeEnum.PM) {
                    outputString += " PM"
                }

                println(outputString)

                return outputString
            }
        }
    }


    mutating func validateNewInput(inputString : String) -> Bool
    {
        switch (self.timeType)
            {
        case TimeTypeEnum.Decimal:
            return self.validateNewInputForDecimal(inputString)
        case TimeTypeEnum.Interval:
            //                  return self.validateNewInputForInterval(inputString)
            return false
        case TimeTypeEnum.AM, TimeTypeEnum.PM:
            var temp : Bool = self.validateNewInputForRawTime(inputString, isMilitaryTime:false)
            println(self.timeIntervalInput)
            return temp
        case TimeTypeEnum.Military:
            var temp : Bool =  self.validateNewInputForRawTime(inputString, isMilitaryTime:true)
            println(self.timeIntervalInput)
            return temp
        default:
            return false
        }
    }


    mutating func validateNewInputForDecimal(inputString : String) -> Bool
    {
        let combinedString : String = self.decimalInput + inputString

        // note: this regex fails on letters-only strings.  not an issue now but something to watch
        let predicate : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES '^[0-9]*(\\.[0-9]*)'")
        let stringTest : Bool = predicate.evaluateWithObject(combinedString)

        if (stringTest) {
            self.decimalInput = combinedString
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    // used to evaluate an incoming string when the string is assumed to represent a raw time (e.g. 5:30am)
    // since the string is being built one character at a time, each character needs to be evaluated separately
    // to ensure that the final time is valid
    mutating func validateNewInputForRawTime(inputString : String, isMilitaryTime : Bool) -> Bool
    {
        let currentString = self.timeIntervalInput[self.timeIntervalIndex]

        // if the incoming value is a ":" assume the user wants to move on to the next section
        // (e.g. hours --> minutes).  Fill in any gaps in the current section, then advance to the next section
        if (inputString == ":") {
            // check to make sure there is a "next" section
            if (self.timeIntervalIndex < self.timeIntervalInput.count - 1)
            {
                // if the current section is incomplete, fill any gaps with 0s
                let prefixString = "00"
                var combinedString = prefixString + currentString
                combinedString = combinedString.substringFromIndex(countElements(combinedString) - 2)
                self.timeIntervalInput[self.timeIntervalIndex] = combinedString

                // go to the next section
                self.timeIntervalIndex++
                return true
            }
            // if the incoming value is a number, evaluate it to make sure it's valid, and if so, add it
        } else {

            let combinedString = currentString + inputString

            // each section (hours, minutes, etc, has its own rules for whether the input is valid
            switch (self.timeIntervalIndex)
            {
                // hours
                case 0:
                    // if empty, accept any number
                    if (countElements(currentString) == 0) {
                        self.timeIntervalInput[self.timeIntervalIndex] = combinedString
                        return true
                        // if one digit exists, make sure total value is less than 12/24 (format depending)
                    } else if (countElements(currentString) == 1) {
                        if ((combinedString.toInt() < 24 && isMilitaryTime) || (combinedString.toInt() < 12)) {
                            self.timeIntervalInput[self.timeIntervalIndex] = combinedString
                            return true
                        }
                        // if both digits exist, skip to the next section and add it
                    } else {
                        self.timeIntervalIndex++
                        self.timeIntervalInput[self.timeIntervalIndex] = inputString
                        return true
                    }
                // minutes, seconds
                case 1, 2:
                    // if empty, accept any number
                    if (countElements(currentString) == 0) {
                        self.timeIntervalInput[self.timeIntervalIndex] = combinedString
                        return true
                        // if one digit exists, make sure total value is less than 60
                    } else if (countElements(currentString) == 1) {
                        if (combinedString.toInt() < 60) {
                            let combinedString = currentString + inputString
                            self.timeIntervalInput[self.timeIntervalIndex] = combinedString
                            return true
                        }
                        // if both digits exist, skip to the next section and add it
                    } else {
                        self.timeIntervalIndex++
                        self.timeIntervalInput[self.timeIntervalIndex] = inputString
                        return true
                    }
                // milliseconds
                case 3:
                    // accept any combined total less than 1000
                    if (combinedString.toInt() < 1000) {
                        let combinedString = currentString + inputString
                        self.timeIntervalInput[self.timeIntervalIndex] = combinedString
                        return true
                    }
                default:
                    break
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

And here's where it's being used (inputs is an array of the above struct):

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @IBAction func addInputCharacter(#sender : UIButton)
    {
        let inputChar : String = String(sender.tag)
        self.inputs[self.currentInput].validateNewInput(inputChar)
        self.updateLabelsAfterInput()
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    func updateLabelsAfterInput()
    {
        self.lblMainLabel.text = self.inputs[self.currentInput].label
        if (self.currentInput == 0) {
            self.lblSecondaryLabel.text = ""
        } else {
            self.lblSecondaryLabel.text = self.inputs[0].label
        }
    }
```

The crash is happening the first time the user enters a number.  I've tested it without updating the label, and the timeIntervalInputs array is getting set perfectly (after entering "1", the array reads [1, , , ], then entering 0 it becomes [10, , , ])

The error message on crash is

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x12aff2cf0)

combinedString2a, immediately before the crash, is storing the correct value ("00").  After the crash, Quick Look says the value is "(None)" and printing the description gives the following message:

> (String) combinedString2a = DW_OP_piece for offset 8: top of stack is
>   not a piece

Comment: What is the value of combinedString2a  where it crashes, before it crashes?

Comment: Also, can you post the error message of the crash?

Comment: also the value of `timeIntervalInput` would help.

Comment: can you, please, share the `timeIntervalInput` array with us?

Comment: I think you need to post the whole class. As it is this code runs just fine in Playground. Perhaps somehow timeIntervalInput gets collected (weak references etc?)

Comment: I have to wonder how many issues like this are just because Swift is so new, and has possibly some teething problems.  As the next beta versions of Xcode come along you may find your issue magically starts working.  Of course, Apple already said they do not guarantee code compatibility between versions of Xcode beta anyway as it will be evolving.  Just something to bear in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've filed a bug report with Apple.  In the meantime, I've found a workaround by replacing the combined strings with NSStrings and using the NSString versions of the methods.

```
var outputString : String = ""
let prefixString : String = "00"

let combinedString1 : NSString = prefixString.stringByAppendingString(self.timeIntervalInput[0])
let combinedString1a : NSString = combinedString1.substringFromIndex(combinedString1.length - 2)
outputString += combinedString1a

let combinedString2 : NSString = prefixString.stringByAppendingString(self.timeIntervalInput[1])
let combinedString2a : NSString = combinedString2.substringFromIndex(combinedString2.length - 2)
outputString += combinedString2a

let combinedString3 : NSString = prefixString.stringByAppendingString(self.timeIntervalInput[2])
let combinedString3a : NSString = combinedString3.substringFromIndex(combinedString3.length - 2)
outputString += combinedString3a

return outputString
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been hitting the same error, and I can only think it's a bug in Swift. Here's a very simple example. txtName is an IBOutlet for a text field in which the user types their name, labResult is a label where the results are placed. In the following code, we hit the error each time in modifyString as soon as we try to call the .lowercaseString method. (I'm very new to Swift, and to iOS programming, so I may be making some stupid error, but I don't know what).

```
@IBAction func butDoIt_Clicked(sender : UIButton) {
    var myName = "Fred Bloggs"
    labResult.text = modifyString(myName) //this works just fine

    if txtName.text
    {
        myName = txtName.text!
        labResult.text = modifyString(myName) //this crashes with EXC-BAD-ACCESS
    }
   }

func modifyString(aName:String) ->String
{
    let lowername = aName.lowercaseString
    let uppername = aName.uppercaseString
    return lowername + "-" + uppername
}
```

Comment: Try `myName = txtName.text! as String` — NSString does not seem to be fully compatible with Swift’s String.